# I hope to give LDAP server new OID object

Tags: ldap, oid, adlds

I am studying LDAP server(ADLDS)

I figured out that extended operation is implemented in ldap server.

For example, oid(1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.11.3) stands for whoami command.

If I give 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.11.3 to ldap server, server would respond who the user is.

In this situation, I hope to make my own command with new oid.

How can I make this possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Some LDAP directory servers will allow you to extend them and define your own extended operation. This needs code and some expertise in the internals of the server.
I would strongly recommend that you consider open source directory servers, if you want to pursue that route, as getting full access to the code will make things easier.